# How can i add a background color to a div(that has an id), that is inside a wrapper?

Tags: html, css

Below is my code. Im using the framework skeleton. I have separate divs that represents three,seven and six columns that equal 16(skeleton is a 16 column framework). Therefore the the 3 divs are all inline accross the screen. The wrapper has a background color grey, therefore making the whole scree grey. However, i want to make the background color of the 3 div classes black. Any ideas? As ive tried to put all 3 divs into another div with an id, and set the background black however did not work?

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="container">       

       <div class="three columns">
            <img src="images/ste.jpg" alt="" height="150px" width="160px" />
            <hr />
       </div>

       <div class="seven columns">
         <div id="namechange" class="six columns">
            <u><h4>Stephen Carter</h4></u>
            <p>I am  currently studentying at Leeds Beckett University, and this module is called Advanced Internet Development B </p>
            <hr />
        </div>
       </div>
     <div id="navchange" class="six columns">
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
        <a href="#">Blog</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
        <hr />

            </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sure this could be easily done using `CSS`. Why don't you read few examples here: `http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp`

Comment: Can you show us your css code when you try to add background color ?

Answer (score 1):

Add background color to your classes

```
.three, .seven, .six{
    background-color:black;
}
```

[Fiddle with skeleton](http://jsfiddle.net/myhafj13/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm thinking to easy, but how about:

```
#wrapper {
    background: grey;
}
.three, .seven, .six {
    background: lightblue;
}
```

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69bybauz/).

If it doesn't work for you, please share your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

//try this css code

```
.three, .seven, .six {
    background-color:#000000 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
#wrapper .three, #wrapper .seven, #wrapper .six {
    background-color:#000000 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be your div#wrapper background color overrides the div#wrapper inside div background color,so add like below:

```
#wrapper{background:grey;}
#wrapper div{background:black;}
```

or add !important like below:

```
#wrapper div{background:black !important;}
```

Answer (score -1):

You just need to do that :

```
<div style="background-color: #000000;">
```

And change the hexadecimal value for the color you want.

Or do that with CSS by usign your classes :

```
.yourClass {
background-color: #000000;
}
```